# move all files and folders into a newly created directory by cli

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-interface

I have realized all files and folders should be in a parent directory which I forgot to create. For example, my folder structure is like this:

```
Parent_folder
  Folder1
  Folder 2
  other files etc...
```

and I want it to become

```
Parent_folder
  My_new_folder
    Folder1
    Folder 2
    other files etc...
```

Could it be done via terminal? Do i have to use shell script for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd (path to the Parent_folder)
mkdir My_new_folder && mv -f -v * My_new_folder
```

The `-f` to not prompt you before overwriting.
The `-v` parameter is used in case there was an error, and would be verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Parent_folder $ ls -1
file1.txt
folder1
folder2
Parent_folder $ mkdir My_new_folder
Parent_folder $ mv * My_new_folder
mv: cannot move 'My_new_folder' to a subdirectory of itself, 'My_new_folder/My_new_folder'
Parent_folder $ tree
.
└── My_new_folder
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── folder1
    └── folder2

3 directories, 1 file
```

The `mv` will show a warning, because it will try to move the new folder into itself, but you can just skip it.

Comment: I thought, that thing would prevent the operation, but it just works with a warning. Thats great, thanks